# Ассциативный массив JS

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
let places = {};
```

Пытаюсь добавить к определённому ключу в конец его значений, новое:

```
places[carriage].push('key2_value3');
```

Но пишет ошибку - places[carriage].push is not a function

Comment: а вы точно уверены что `places[carriage]` существует и там массив?

Comment: Мне приходит цифра, как можно эту цифру добавить в массив как ключ?

Comment: Нет примера данных.
Изначально это просто объявление places = [];
Потом мне нужно создавать ключ и для него список значений добавлять.

Comment: Мне нужно key2_value3 добавить к определённому ключу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let places = {}` это литерал объекта. 
`let places = []` вот это новый пустой массив.
При использовании метода push() не нужно указывать индекс массива. Этот метод сам вставит элемент в **конец массива**.
Так что ваш пример будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
let places = [];
places.push('key2_value3');
```

Если вам нужно создать объект, у которого будут пары ключ/значение, тогда да. Нужно будет сделать примерно так.

```
let places = {};
places.carriage = 'value';
```

Через точку мы можем добавлять новые поля в объект и присваивать им значения.
Если поле вашего объекта должно быть массивом, то сначала его нужно определить.

```js
let places = {};
places.carriage = [];
places.carriage.push('new value');
places.carriage.push('new value'); // добавим ещё один элемент в массив
places.newField = []; // второй ключ-массив
places.newField.push('anothe value');
places.newField.push('anothe value 2');
let otherKey = 'other';
places[otherKey] = [];
places[otherKey].push('other');
console.log(places)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92495/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-sazonov---js).

Answer (score 1):

**Объект** `{}` в `javasctipt` представлен [ассоциативным массивом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2), но его не принято называть массивом, его принято называть **Объектом**.

Вероятно ваш вопрос возник потому что Вы были знакомы с этой структурой данных раньше чем начали изучать javascript.

Когда в `javascript` идет речь про массив имеется в виду [`Array()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) или `[]`

И следуя Вашей логике работы с объектом вы вероятно хотели нечто такое

```js
let places = {};

// тут я предположил что carriage это все таки строка а не переменная
push('carriage1', 'key2_value3');    
push('carriage1', 'key2_value4');
push('carriage2', 'key2_value1');    
push('carriage2', 'key2_value2');

function push(key, value){
   // проверяем наличие ключа в объекте
   if (!places[key]) {
      // если его нет присваиваем значению ключа новый пустой массив
      places[key] = [];
   } 
   // теперь можно смело добавлять элементы в массив, 
   // который лежит в объекте под ключом значение которого передано через переменну `key`
   places[key].push(value) 
}

console.log(places)
```

Коротко это можно записать вот так:

```js
let places = {};

let push = (a, b) => (places[a] || (places[a] = [])).push(b);

push('carriage1', 'key2_value3');   
push('carriage1', 'key2_value4'); 
console.log(places)
```